# Call server side method from the front end

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, telerik-grid

Hi I have a teletik rid rad grid, is there a way to call a server side method from the front end and passing in an argument ? e.g.

**Front end (aspx page):**

```
<Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="QuestionAnswer" DataType="System.String"
                HeaderText="Answer" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="QuestionAnswer" UniqueName=QuestionAnswer"
                FilterControlAltText="Filter QuestionAnswer column">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="QuestionAnswerDate" DataType="System.String"
                HeaderText="Answered Date" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="QuestionAnswerDate" UniqueName="QuestionAnswerDate"
                FilterControlAltText="Filter QuestionAnswerDate column"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>

            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="QuestionAnsweredByID" DataType="System.String"
                HeaderText="Answered By" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="QuestionAnsweredByID" UniqueName="QuestionAnsweredByID"
                FilterControlAltText="Filter QuestionAnsweredByID column">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

</Columns>
```

On the page this loads the rad grid with the columns and the data. For the "Answered By" column it displays an user id...

What I need however is to pass this ID to a method in the back end/server side that takes in a parameter and gives me a user name (first name + last name retrieved from the DB)

**The method I have in the code behind is as follows:**

```
public string GetName(int userID)
    {
        return UserHelper.GetUser(userID));
    }
```

Back to my original question is there a way to call the method from the front end so that I get the correct user name in the "Answered By" column instead of just the user id?

**Is it possible to call the method like so:**

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="<%# Eval GetName(QuestionAnsweredByID) %>" DataType="System.String"
            HeaderText="Answered By" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="QuestionAnsweredByID" UniqueName="QuestionAnsweredByID"
            FilterControlAltText="Filter QuestionAnsweredByID column">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call that method from front-end, and you are almost their at the target, if you made a little change then your code will work. The calling should be like this:

```
DataField="<%#GetName(Eval("QuestionAnsweredByID")) %>"
```